# Is it ok to use github as a file hosting?

Tags: github

Is it ok to use github as a file hosting ? Now i dont mean it like cloud hosting like dropbox.

For example:

https://dribbble.com/shots/1722076-Free-iPhone-6-4-7-inch-Template-PSD?list=users&offset=57

This guy designed an iPhone 6 template and he uploaded his work to Github for people to download it:

https://github.com/Ramotion/free-iPhone6-template

Is that ok ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Terms Of Service on [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service/) there is no mentioning of not being able to host files on their service, however as always you are responsible for the content.

Comment: Analogy: Legality does not infer morality. ToS allowance does not infer correctness. Abusing Git as non-versioned binary storage has always been stupid, and there's nothing "okay" about doing that. </pedantry>

Answer (score 1):

As @TheVril already stated, it's ok.  But be aware of the following restrictions and possibilities:

- [Files are not allowed to exceed 100 MB and respositories should not exceed 1 GB.](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/#file-and-repository-size-limitations)
- [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/) ([GitHub support coming soon](https://github.com/early_access/large_file_storage)) might be better suited to store large files. (Compared to a git repo.)
- You can [create releases](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/) to ship binary files.